# Get notifications for high CPU usage

Tags: macos, performance, big-sur, apple-silicon

My new laptop has an M1 chip and no fan, and this is great, but it also makes it hard for me to find out when the CPU has been running high (and consuming more battery than usual).

How can I make it show notifications whenever the CPU has been running high for a while?

Comment: Would running Activity Monitor minimized on the CPU tab work as well?

Comment: @nohillside That's what I do atm, but I'd much prefer a notification and a solution that doesn't require an extra item in the dock.

Comment: Why do you need notification? The computer has temperature management built-in.

Comment: @benwiggy Because high CPU usage means worse performance, both in terms of speed and battery.

Comment: Wouldn't you notice reduced performance anyway, even if no fan gives you an audible signal?

Comment: If I'm bouncing audio in Logic Pro, then high CPU usage is good performance. Bad performance would be using 10% of the CPU and taking ages. So what will you do when you get notified - stop using it? Genuinely curious what the use case is.

Comment: @benwiggy I'd sometimes have processes go unresponsive (ex: due to a software bug) and stay at 100% CPU usage until I force-quit them.

Comment: also u can notice long term high cpu usage if the laptop is warmer than usual

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/).  This is the best paid app for showing, via the menubar, how your Mac is performing.  In addition it also can send notifications for a number of performance related events - and that includes high CPU.

Here is the preference screen for setting alerts:

[image]

You can download iStat Menus for free and use it for 14 days before deciding whether to pay.